# Python how to capitalize first letter of a word and last three letters

Tags: python, string

I am trying to capitalize first letter and last three letter of a matched phrase for example having a string:

`test = "TEAM_DEV_FTW_SOMETHING"`

from that string I want the result to get `Team Dev FTW`

What I tried so far:

`team = " ".join(map(lambda x: x.capitalize(), test.name.split("_")[:3]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
test = "TEAM_DEV_FTW_SOMETHING"
team = " ".join(map(lambda x: x.capitalize(), test.split("_")[:3]))
team = team[:-3] + team[-3:].upper()
print(team)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `enumerate`:

```
"_".join([i.upper() if n==2 else i.capitalize() 
          for n, i in enumerate(s.split("_")[:3])])
```

Output:

```
'Team_Dev_FTW'
```